# what's wrong with my Self-Executing Anonymous Function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous

I try to write a javascript `Self-Executing Anonymous Function`

```
window.App = window.App || {}

    (function (global) {
        global.test = function () {
            console.log('test');
        }
    })(App);

$(function () {
    App.test();
})
```

but the fire bug tell me: `({}) is not a function`

then I try move the `(app)` in, like:

```
(function (global) {
    global.test = function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
}(App));
```

then the firebug tell me :

```
App is not defined
```

So wht's wrong with my code?How can I do it in right way?

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/rhdkU/1/)

Comment: This code looks a little strange to me so I won't provide an answer, but shouldn't there be some code between the curly braces on the first line?

Comment: @JezenThomas no, the {} is just a way of creating an empty object.  You can see it gets passed into the function as *global*, where it gets a method *test* defined on it.

Comment: That is a nice example for problems with semicolon insertion in the wild. Kids, never forget your semicolons!

Comment: Very interesting. Great question; not sure why it's been downvoted. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.App = window.App || {};
```

You are missing a semicolon there!

Comment: JavaScript does automatic semicolon insertion at the end of every line, if this does not result in a syntax error.  The two lines should be equivalent.

Comment: @cdhowie Not always, and this is a perfect case and point.

Comment: @cdhowie no, a semicolon is required here since the next token is a `(`.

Comment: And there you have it, a [semicolon saves the day](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/jczcx/).

Comment: Ridiculous! I think the OP deliberately constructed this question to prove a point.

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon to your first row

```
window.App = window.App || {};
```

JS thought that that the parentheses on row 3 was part of your new empty object on row 1.